# Mask UIView and pan / pinch an uiimagview

Tags: ios, uiview, uipangesturerecognizer, uipinchgesturerecognizer

i have this task as you can see in image:

[image]

please note that in the circular dashed view i need to add pan gesture to move uiimage and pinch to zoom in / out.

How would you accomplish this?

thanks million

Comment: before adding the pan/pinch, did you finish the UI with proper scrollview and masked the circular view ? I beleieve adding those two is not difficult. Please provide code of what you tried.

Comment: Try adding your gesture recognizers on the mask instead of the image view. Then scale or pan your image view relatively.